# Wordpress save and share cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using the WooCommerce Save and Share Shopping Cart for my Wordpress shop site. 
I have installed the Wordpress and plugin on both local and remote server, and when I send the cart from local server, it sends successfully, but when it comes to remote, it gives and error, "Sorry, Your email can not be sent at this time"

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. 
So first I had to install & enable to php sendemail module `apt-get install sendmail` and configure it `sudo sendmailconfig`. Then I installed `wp-mail-smtp` plugin from here [enter link description here](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)

And setup the SMTP settings (used gmail smtp). Now you are good to go.